# Network manager no default route

Tags: networking, network-manager, routing

This problem started about three weeks ago, apparently after an update.

When I connect to a new wifi network, I reach local connectivity only; my laptop connects and receives an IP address successfully (verified via syslog) but `ping 8.8.8.8` returns `connect: Network is unreachable`.

The routing table always looks something like this:

```
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

In particular, there is no default route specified. I think this is the problem. If I run the command

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.2.1 wlp2s0
```

Then everything works; I can ping google.com, but network-manager still thinks I have only local connectivity.

If I use a static IP instead and specify 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver, everything works. If I use a static IP and do not specify 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver, I can ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com.

How can I get network-manager to properly automatically assign a default route?

Answer (score 5):

The issues is most probably related to the route configurations not being set in the wireless device NM configs. try to edit the file for your connection manually, you will find it here, vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YOUR_WIFI_NAME

under the ipv4 section add (while this should be the default):
`never-default=false`

You also have to edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Also if you found that `managed=true` in the first place then that could be the issue for not automatically adding the routes, try to change it to false, and don't do the previous ipv4 step and then:

`service network-manager restart`

Or if you are using Debian 11+:

`service NetworkManager restart`

Comment: I had the same problem, just with my regular ethernet connection. I both had to set `managed=true` and add the corresponding entry `never-default=false` to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0` to get a default route, I couldn't configure it with the GUI elements for some reason (I unchecked `use connection only for resources on its network` but to no avail).

Answer (score 1):

I again ran into this problem. In the log files, I always could see that network manager only entered state `CONNECTED_LOCAL`. I tried fiddling with the `never-default` and `managed` settings, but nothing worked.
I solved the problem after discovering what was missing with `nmcli`:

```
$ nmcli connection edit eth0
...
nmcli> print
...
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.223.9/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
...
```

Obviously the gateway was missing. I added it like so:

```
nmcli> set ipv4.gateway 192.168.223.2
nmcli> save
Connection 'eth0' (...) successfully updated.
```

Now NetworkManager says it enters state `CONNECTED_GLOBAL` in the log files.

Answer (score 1):

There were problems to connect to my WiFi network with Network Manager using postmarketOS on my Jolla smartphone but I found a solution that could help users of other Linux distributions also.

I had to install dhclient and replace `dhcp=internal` with `dhcp=dhclient` below `[main]` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Then I had to restart Network Manager with the command `sudo service networkmanager restart` (solution based on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232833 / https://forum.salixos.org/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=7284).

Network Manager was then connected to the WiFi network but I could not ping an IP address like 1.1.1.1, there was no default route. To fix this issue, I had to execute this command: `sudo dhclient wlan0`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Waheed, I found that under

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired\ connection\ 1.nmconnection
```

under `[ipv4]`, there was an entry called `ignore-auto-routes=true`.

I found the meaning of `ignore-auto-routes` [here](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-ipv4.html) and the text there seems to suggest that that probably is the cause.

While changing that file with an editor works, I in the end fixed it by opening the setting, Network, Wired, Settings, IPv4 and there under Routes 'Automatic' wasn't chosen. After I chose that the problem was solved. Unsure how it had gotten the wrong value.
[image: Wired network settings]

Answer (score 0):

You should have default route (0.0.0.0) information in your routing table or `netstat -rn`.

[image: ip r output]

[image: netstat -rn output]